# The method 'set_age' isn't defined for the class 'Person'. in dart

Tags: dart

I am new to `dart` and I am getting this error when try to set a value to a variable (which is a private variable) and I am using `getters` and `setters`

but I am getting this error:

> The method 'set_age' isn't defined for the class 'Person'.

Here is how my code looks like.

```
class Person{
  String firstName, lastName;
  int _pAge;
  double pSalary;

//  syntactic sugar
  Person(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.pSalary);

//  Named constructor
  Person.origin(){
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    _pAge = 0;
    pSalary = 0.0;
  }

  String fullName() => this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;

//  getters and setters for _pAge
  set set_age(int age){
    _pAge =  age;
  }

  int get get_age => _pAge;
}

main() {
  Person p1 = new Person("Jananath", "Banuka", 15000.00);
  Person p2 = new Person("Thilina", "Kalansooriya", 55000.00);

  p1.set_age(10); //this is where the error is coming from

  print(p1.fullName());
  print(p2.fullName());
}
```

Comment: `set_age = 10;` but give names like set_something not clever idea

Answer (score 2):

You are not writing idiomatic Dart, and that is probably why you are thinking of setters as functions. Setters are called by assigning to them, so instead of `p1.set_age(10)` it should just be `p1.age = 10;`.

Your code, as idiomatic Dart, would look like:

```dart
class Person{
  String firstName, lastName;
  int age;
  double salary;

  Person(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.salary) : age = 0;

  Person.origin() 
    : firstName = "", lastName = "", age = 0, salary = 0; 

  String get fullName => "$firstName $lastName";
}

main() {
  Person p1 = new Person("Jananath", "Banuka", 15000.00);
  Person p2 = new Person("Thilina", "Kalansooriya", 55000.00);

  p1.age = 10;

  print(p1.fullName);
  print(p2.fullName);
}
```

This makes the `age` a public field. There is no need to hide a private field behind a public setter/getter which then just forward to the field. You can just make the field public directly.

Dart has setters and getters precisely because you are then *not* prevented from adding logic to the set/get operation in the future. You can always change

```dart
int age;
```

to

```dart
int _age;
int get age => _age;
set age(int value) {
  log("SETTING AGE: $value");
  _age = value;
}
```

at a later point if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling you setter as a method. You should either change how you use your setter or change your setter to a method:

```
class Person1 {
  int _pAge;

  set set_age(int age) =>_pAge = age;
  int get get_age => _pAge;
}

class Person2 {
  int _pAge;

  void set_age(int age) => _pAge = age;
  int get_age() => _pAge;
}

void main() {
  final p1 = Person1();
  p1.set_age = 10;
  print(p1.get_age);

  final p2 = Person2();
  p2.set_age(10);
  print(p2.get_age());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### p1.set_age = 10;

```
  set set_age(int age){
    _pAge =  age;
  }
```

### p1.set_age(10);

```
  void set_age(int age){
    _pAge =  age;
  }
```